# ... google maps Javascript API not supported. Use another Browser

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, browser, notsupportedexception

I am using two different third party programs (different companies) that apparently use the Google Maps Javascript API. When they load the map, the world map is shown, but an Error message is displayed: "Der von Ihnen verwendete Browser wird von Google Maps Javascript API nicht unterstützt. Verwenden Sie einen anderen Browser". (Translation: The browser you are using is not supported by Google Maps Javascript API. Use another browser). I am using Windows 7 and Internet Explorer 11.0.48. Early 2017 the programs were working correctly. I changed the default browser to Chrome using the option provided by chrome, but the error still appears.
Is there a workaround on the user side?
Regards
Peter

One of the programs is downloadable from http://www.codres.de/google-map-saver (GMS.NET), the other one came with a GPS logger from Canmore GPS on CD ROM and dates from 2013.
Both show the same behaviour, GMS.NET after clicking the button "Go to location", GPS Photo Tagger right after start up. The english error message is "You are using a browser that is not supported by the Google Maps JavaScript API. Consider changing your browser. **Learn More**, **Dismiss**". When I click "Learn more" I am told that IE 11 is my current browser. When I click an internet link in an e-mail Google Chrome is used (as default browser). It seems to me that the JavaScript API does not recognise Chrome as the default browser. IE11 is not run in compatibility mode. The Notebook I am using runs Windows 7 64bits.

I clicked the link in geocodezip's response. This sample works correctly calling Chrome (even when I copy the code into MS Word). When I open the link in IE11 it also works correctly. Is it possible to define the InternetExplorer as default browser in the Javascript API? This might be the reason for the different behaviour of the geocodezip sample and my programs. In this case the programs would have to be mended.

Comment: I don't get that error message in IE 11.0.47 on [this Google Maps Javascript API v3 page](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3.html).  Please provide a [mcve] that exhibits the error.

Comment: You should check if your browser is running in compatibility mode. The compatibility mode of IE is not supported by Google Maps JavaScript API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/browsersupport

Answer (score 3):

It seems a number of programs show this error since late 2017. The underlying problem here seems to be that they are all using an embedded webbrowser relying on IE technology. This embedded webbrowser needs to signal the proper IE version to the Google Maps JS library. Unfortunately, only the programmers of that software can do this. Adding the following to the page's source usually helps:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Look here
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.31&key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
```

see v=3.31
latest is now 3.32 and if is not specified it will use the latest

And here 
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/key/
check all api restrictions
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with users on Windows 7 IE and no Chrome browser installed.

Added the following line :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />
```

Which seems to have resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Google has dropped support for legacy systems (like Windows 7, earlier versions of IE) in Javascript API even with **v3**. It was working until this month, and what i also noticed that adding "v=3" string to maps api URL is no longer helping IE clients to run it without error. It's not a good behaviour of Google that there are older clients using v3 api with older IE verions which were working perfectly until this month.