# Geocoder not support in Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

In My software am using Geocoder, suddenly it not working in Internet explorer.I am not able to find exact issue.I can see  the following Popup "You are using a browser that is not supported by the Google Maps JavaScript API. Consider changing your browser"
Guys Please assist me to resolve this issue.

Comment: The message is clear: "Consider changing your browser". That, or use a different library.

Comment: Okay.Thank you Peter ,we need any scope to work IE also..Because our client mostly work Internet explorer(IE 9,10,11 Edge).

Comment: It sounds like you might be using compatibility mode in IE. It should be fine using IE 10 and 11, but if you emulate or use older version of IE it's not supported: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/browsersupport.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below line in your code may help to solve the issue.

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> 

or

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />
```

Reference:

[… google maps Javascript API not supported. Use another Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47360438/google-maps-javascript-api-not-supported-use-another-browser)